# Div card misplacing

Tags: html, css

This is my [Portfolio](http://patrykponichtera.com/) i'm working on

The first time you enter the website the yellow Wakey card is below the sidebar (it should be on the right side of the sidebar.

And after refreshing the website it goes into the right position
What can be causing this?

This is the css of the content div where the card is located

```
     #content
{
    width:70%;
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;

}
```

And this is the sidebars

```
#sidebar
{
    background-color:#4b4b4b;
    margin:0px;
    margin-left:5%;
    width:400px;
    height:1000px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px #000000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px #000000;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px #000000;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

You can see the html from the website so i won't post it to keep it short

On IE it's displaying properly, it gives me this problem on chrome

UPDATE:
I've changed the #content-wrapper display to `display:inline;` now, but it didn't help

Comment: working for me in FF & Safari, too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not float your sidebar? and let the #content position itself in the normal document flow.. you might want to set width for #content also..

```
#sidebar
{
  background-color:#4b4b4b;
  margin:0px;
  margin-left:5%;
  width:400px;
  height:1000px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px #000000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px #000000;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px #000000;
  float: left;
```

}

```
#content
{
 float: left;
}
```

Comment: @DoubleP90 welcome.. also when you choose to float elements you should plan about clearing the floats as well or apply an clearfix.. google the term `clearfix` to find more about it.. here is a good resource http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/